# MAX856 Low-Battery Indicator Question

Tags: voltage, batteries

the MAX856 says it has a low-battery indicaitor. My setup has a single 3.7v nominal LiPo pouch and I want it to trigger the low-battery at 3.4V.

Datasheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX856-MAX859.pdf

[image]

**Does this mean that I should take my battery + terminal, put it through a resistive divider and choose the resistors such that 3.4V at BAT+ gives 1.25V at the resisitve divider output ?**

Comment: That's what I assume should be done. I do not see any other likely meaning of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I should take my battery + terminal, put it through a resistive divider and choose the resistors such that 3.4V at BAT+ gives 1.25V at the resisitve divider output ?

Yes, that's exactly right.

The MAX856 [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX856-MAX859.pdf) has this example of implementing this - see `R3` and `R4` in this schematic:

---

[image: MAX 856 datasheet Figure 2a]

[image: MAX 856 datasheet Low-Battery Detection]

---

As an example, if you use E96 resistor values, then a quick calculation suggests 150 kΩ for `R4` and 255 kΩ for `R3` gets you close to your desired 3.4 V low-battery value and stays below the 300 kΩ suggested maximum resistor value - but do check my calculations.